# What's wrong with using $RANDOM + $FLOOR in bash?

Tags: bash, random

Reading this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

```
#  If you need a random integer greater than a lower bound,
#+ then set up a test to discard all numbers below that.

FLOOR=200

number=0   #initialize
while [ "$number" -le $FLOOR ]
do
  number=$RANDOM
done
echo "Random number greater than $FLOOR ---  $number"
echo

   # Let's examine a simple alternative to the above loop, namely
   #       let "number = $RANDOM + $FLOOR"
   # That would eliminate the while-loop and run faster.
   # But, there might be a problem with that. What is it?
```

I have been not able to come up with a decent answer to the question in the last comment. That's the way I always generated my pseudorandom numbers in other languages (C/C++, Pascal), and had no problems -- is this something relevant only to Bash?

Comment: FYI, the ABS is a very poor reference -- they have a long history of demonstrating bad practices in their examples and ignoring requests that they fix bugs, and this one is no exception. (Use of `[ ]` instead of `(( ))` for math; use of unquoted variables; etc).

Comment: What is your question? Is it about the commented code?

Comment: Anyhow -- **if** the maximum value that RANDOM could return were also the maximum value that bash's built-in integer math could handle, then there would be a serious bug in the commented-form, because doing the addition could cause an overflow. That bug doesn't actually exist, since the maximum value reached by `$RANDOM` is 32768, and bash's math can go well above that -- see again re: the ABS being a horrible, frequently-inaccurate reference.

Comment: Could it be that the `+` was supposed to be a `%`, and it's hinting at the bias introduced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In programming languages where your random-number generator could give you values up to just below the overflow point, the latter code would have a bug wherein items within the range between `MAXINT - FLOOR` and `MAXINT` would overflow.

Bash does not have this bug, but the reference you are reading is evidently written without that awareness.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's an undocumented feature!

Answer (score 2):

`$RANDOM` returns a random 16-bit integer, i.e. the range is `0` to `32767`. I think the question in the comment presumes that you only want to change the lower bound to `$FLOOR`, but still expect the upper bound to be `32767`. If you use `$RANDOM + $FLOOR`, you're also increasing the upper bound to `32967`, which is not expected.

You can do it without a loop, though:

```
number=$(($FLOOR + (($RANDOM*32567)/32767)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue ABS sees. Here's a sample test program where I pick numbers between 10 to 19. I track the chosen numbers with the arrays `right_way` (the way ABS says to do it) and `wrong_way` (The way they said is incorrect, but don't explain why).:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a right_way
declare -a wrong_way

for count in {1..10000}
do
    #
    # Generating Random Number between 10 and 20
    #
    number=0
    while (( $number < 10 ))
    do
        (( number = $RANDOM % 20 ))
    done
    right_way[$number]=$(( ${right_way[$number]} + 1 ))
    number=$(($RANDOM % 10 + 10 ))
    wrong_way[$number]=$((${wrong_way[$number]} + 1 ))
done

printf "%10s   %10s   %10s\n" "Number" "Right Way" "Wrong Way"
for index in {10..19}
do
    printf "%10d   %10d   %10d\n" $index ${right_way[$index]} ${wrong_way[$index]}
done
```

And here's the results:

```
    Number    Right Way    Wrong Way
        10         1027         1006
        11         1001          998
        12          996          974
        13          985         1003
        14         1065          991
        15          990          990
        16          959         1063
        17         1023          989
        18          967          988
        19          987          998
```

I would expect each number to be chosen around 1000 times on the average, and it's pretty close with both methods.